# Compiler error - mismatched types when trying to implement a proxy pattern in rust

Tags: rust

I trying to implement a proxy in Rust, allowing me to read a model, but also to perform mutable operations. To avoid having two different implementations of the proxy (one mutable, one immutable), I made the proxy implementation generic.

I would like the proxy to create other instances of self, in different situations, and this is where I got a type mismatch.

The code below reproduces the problem I have:

```rust
use std::borrow::{Borrow, BorrowMut};

struct Model {
    data: Vec<u32>,
}

impl Model {
    fn get_proxy(&self) -> Proxy<&Model> {
        Proxy::new(self)
    }

    fn get_proxy_mut(&mut self) -> Proxy<&mut Model> {
        Proxy::new(self)
    }
}

struct Proxy<M: Borrow<Model>> {
    model: M
}

impl<M: Borrow<Model>> Proxy<M> {
    fn new(model: M) -> Self {
        Self {model}
    }

    fn get_another(&self) -> Proxy<M> {
        // FIRST ERROR here
        self.model.borrow().get_proxy()
    }
}

impl<M: BorrowMut<Model>> Proxy<M> {
    fn get_another_mut(&mut self) -> Proxy<M> {
        // SECOND ERROR here
        self.model.borrow_mut().get_proxy_mut()
    }
}
```

The first compiler error looks like

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\sandbox.rs:28:9
   |
21 | impl<'m, M: Borrow<Model>> Proxy<M> {
   |          - this type parameter
...
26 |     fn get_another(&self) -> Proxy<M> {
   |                              -------- expected `Proxy<M>` because of return type
27 |         // FIRST ERROR here
28 |         self.model.borrow().get_proxy()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `M`, found `&Model`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Proxy<M>`
              found struct `Proxy<&Model>`
```

Any idea how to fix the first error? (I assume the second one will be fixed in a similar way).

Comment: I would suggest you to not try to do that. Just duplicate the code for the mutable and shared references, or use a macro.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I was hoping I can avoid the two solutions you mentioned, because both are hard to maintain for complex interfaces. I keep them as the last resort, still hoping there is a more elegant solution for proxying...